# Two page redirection on a single Javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on a page. That passes two parameters, one is the URL that it need to open a new window or tab (How ever the browser configured). And an ID

```
<input onclick="doSomething("http://url", "id123")" />
```

What I need done is open a new window/tab to the URL, and then on the original tab/window redirect to a new /contrller/idxxx

Here is my method but it doesn't work

```
var doSomething = function(url, id) {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
  document.location="/mycontroller/doSomething?id=" + id
}
```

Anyone have any suggestion? And no I can not use a form or anything else. Just strictly Javascript within this method.

Comment: Sorry that was my typo. `onclick='doSomething("http://url", "id123")'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps make use of of the `<a>` tag -- would the following work for you?

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="doSomething('id123')" href="http://url">Click me to open new tag with href URL and process the onclick function</a>
```

You'll open the new tab with whatever is in the `href` attribute, you'll also have the convenience of processing the url change within the `doSomething()` method.

```
var doSomething = function(id) {
  document.location="/mycontroller/doSomething?id=" + id
}
```

Comment: DOM tag inline events, you can't escape `"` chars

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Didn't think about basic html. Been relying on javascript to do everything for me too much.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I tend to rely too much on javascript too, been trying to change my thought and see what css and html options are available. Good luck with the rest of your code!

Answer (score 0):

Check your use of quotes. You are using double quotes in the script, so all it sees is:

```
onclick="doSomething("
```

Also change it to type='button'?

also check your js console and see if there are any errors. that usually will let you know if it's a code error or some kind of browser security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost seems fine expect javascript `event`

change

```
<input onclick="doSomething("http://url", "id123")" />
```

to

```
<input onclick="doSomething('http://url', 'id123')" />
```

NOTE: you can't escape `" '` char by `\` in inline event function use opposite quote in javascript function from DOM element attribute qoute

Comment: It was not my character escape. I know the window.open got executed, but once that happened, I loose focus of the script and it won't continue to document.location for the second redirect. But the href did it for me.